# MainAxisSize.min not working in custom dialog

Tags: flutter, autosize, customdialog

### **EDIT**

Using the methods I tried, and the answers I got I couldn't achieve the auto-size effect and always got the dialog at its full height, so I switched from using `Scaffold` to `Containers`. If there is a checked way of doing it with `Scaffold` feel free to post it. Thanks.

---

### Question

I'm trying to make my dialog auto-size to fit all its content using MainAxisSize.min in my Scaffold Column widget, but I'm still getting the widget at its full length. Why the MainAxisSize.min doesn't work here?

This is the code of dialog:

```
class AddSockPopup extends Dialog {
  const AddSockPopup({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, StateSetter setState){
        return Dialog(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: _buildChild(context, setState),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _buildChild(BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sock details'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple[400],
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [...],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfmbu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Scaffold` with `Column` and set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`:

```dart
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Scaffold(
        // ...
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: This somehow makes the whole scaffold collapse, so to correct that I have put it in an Expanded widget, thou it's still in it's full length...

Answer (score 0):

@Babushka Use the `ConstrainedBox` widget to allow for dynamic height adjustment of the dialog. It will automatically adjust based on your content.

```
ConstrainedBox(
                 
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
                    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                  ),

                  child: [Your widget]
         
                ),
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: Tried it and still got full-width Dialog, think that the Scaffold is a bit strange with all this constraints stuff

Comment: we will provide you example code for the dialog